# classify data using RTextTool package

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I can't seem to figure out how to classify new data.  So, after a 
model has been built, I'd like to use it to classify new data as it 
comes in.
let's say that I have a dataset called tweets which tweets[,1] contains a text tweets[,2] is the polarity of each tweet (positive or negative )

```
matrix= create_matrix(tweets[,1], language="english",minDocFreq = 2,stripWhitespace = TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE ) 

container = create_container(matrix, as.numeric(as.factor(tweets[,2])),
                         trainSize=1:190000, testSize=190001:210000,virgin=FALSE)

models = train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT" , "SVM", "RF", "BAGGING", "TREE"))
results = classify_models(container, models)
```

i want now to apply the differents models that i have created on a test data called newdf where newdf[,1] represents a vector of comments

```
predMatrix <- create_matrix(newdf[,1], originalMatrix=matrix,language="english",minDocFreq = 2,stripWhitespace = TRUE,
                        removeStopwords=TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE ,weighting=tm::weightTf,
                        stemWords=TRUE )


predSize = length(tweets2[,1]);
predictionContainer <- create_container(predMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), 
testSize=1:predSize, virgin=TRUE)
results = classify_models(predictioncontainer, models)
```

is this the right way to do it ?